# Get all records that satisfy this month in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get all the records that occur for during the month.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    all_day INT NOT NULL,
    start INTEGER NOT NULL,
    end INTEGER NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    creator INTEGER NOT NULL,
    url TEXT NOT NULL,
    id TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (ID)
);
```

And the query I was using, which is wrong, is:

```
select count(*) as event_count from
  (select title from event
  where (strftime('%m', datetime(end, 'unixepoch')) - 1) =
 (strftime('%m', 'now') + 0) group by title);
```

I'm not sure where the error, appreciate help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need nested selects.

You should have `title` in the projection.

The easier way to get month is: `strftime('%m',end,'unixepoch')`

Putting it together...

`sqlite> CREATE TABLE event (
   ...>     title TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     all_day INT NOT NULL,
   ...>     start INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     end INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     description TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     creator INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     url TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     id TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     UNIQUE (ID)
   ...> );
sqlite> insert into event values ("foo",0,0,5667567567,'',9,'','');
sqlite> select title, strftime('%m',end,'unixepoch') from event;
foo|08
sqlite> select title, count(*) as eventcount from event where (strftime('%m','now') + 5) = (strftime('%m',end,'unixepoch') + 0) group by title;
foo|1
sqlite>`

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand the need for the `+ 5`...and is the `+ 0` needed for some type casting?

Comment: I think the +5 was just for your example, ` select title, count(*) as eventcount from event where (strftime('%m','now') + 0) = (strftime('%m',end,'unixepoch') + 0) group by title;` should be sufficient for me, correct?

Comment: Yes, the +5 was just to match my arbitrary unixtime 5667567567 to today's month. Some addition is necessary if you want any adjustment of the month (as the original question did) to convert the output of strftime from text to int.

Comment: Well I need it to be generic, that is whatever the current month is, give me all the events.

Comment: Ah, well I can handle that with correct code, thanks!